# PHP "header" function

Tags: php, html

I have a small form with 2 inputs and a submit button. When the button is pressed, the variables are saved, and then the user is redirected to a new page.

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['coord1']) and isset($_POST['coord2'])) {
    $coord1 = $_POST['coord1'];
    $coord2 = $_POST['coord2'];
    $_SESSION['coord1'] = $coord1;
    $_SESSION['coord2'] = $coord2;
    header("Location: http://localhost/isi/app/index.php ");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The problem is that I always get an Error 404 even if the path is correct. If I copy the path and access it through browser, the page is displayed... Why is the path not working inside this function?

Comment: I dont know..  But just try to remove spaces in header sentence

Comment: Please take a short look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is typically.

Comment: I just realised that instead of redirecting me to http://localhost/isi/app/index.php , the given path, it redirects me to http://localhost/isi/index_submit ..... I mention that the initial path was http://localhost/isi/app/index.php. Any idea where the random "_submit" came from?

Comment: @DanielConstantinescu add ob_start(); in your header section And Update this header("Location: http://localhost/isi/app/index.php "); with header("Location:  index.php ");